# Convert Old Netbeans 3.6 Large Java Project (2 GB Source) to New Netbeans 7 IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a large Java Project (almost **2 GB**). This project runs perfect with **Netbeans 3.6** as it compile files as user wants (Press F9), but when I import that project to **New Netbeans 7**, it goes to auto build and then Heap size Error and Netbens stop working. How can I import old Netbenas 3.6 Project in New IDE. I am ok with any New Modern IDE not only Netbeans 7.

Comment: How could you end with 2GB of source? A lot of images? How much "real code" you have in there?

Comment: This project is very old and real code is around 1 GB, And as old Netbeans create class file at same place of java file. So Source size with Java + Class file is 1.7 GB

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how it can be solved. But the most important thing is.

It is an anti-pattern if any `project build` depend on IDE support.

Consider using popular build tools like `maven` or `ant`.

So, make required modification to use `maven/ant`. And get the any kind of IDE's build support without any hassle!

Answer (score 1):

On a separate note 
(from Kowser's) you could try manually setting heap sizes in your Netbeans `netbeans.conf`

http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/

Perhaps your old config already had such settings and your new install didn't preserve them?

Further, Netbeans discontinued suport for [Swing Application Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Application_Framework) perhaps your code had such dependencies.